# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/shopify_app/request_storage_access.js")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, assets

I am using Shopify_app gem with application. I have updated my `shopify_app gem version 8.2.0 to 11.7.1`

After doing gem updates I started getting the following error for the request_storage_access file in production

```
rails s -e production

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/shopify_app/request_storage_access.js"):
```

I run command for rake assets:precomplie but still facing the same error after run this command too.

Environment info:

Browser: Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ruby: 2.5.7
Rails: '~> 5.2.0'
Shopify App: 11.7.1

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of using Sprockets in Rails. Either kill off your use Sprockets and use Webpack or if you for some reason still need to use Sprockets, downgrade to version < 4 which removes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a team I am working with to solive this issue n addition to running

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile`

We also have to set the following environment variable in

app/config/enviroments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```